# What is the truly correct usage of -S parameter on weka classifier A1DE?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

So I'm using weka 3.7.11 in a Windows machine (and runnings bash scripts with cygwin), and I found an inconsistency regarding the AODE classifier (which in this version of weka, comes from an add-on package).

Using Averaged N-Dependencies Estimators from the GUI, I get the following configuration (from an example that worked alright in the Weka Explorer):

```
weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Discretize -F -B 10 -M -1.0 -R first-last" -W weka.classifiers.bayes.AveragedNDependenceEstimators.A1DE -- -F 1 -M 1.0 -S
```

So I modified this to get the following command in my bash script:

```
java -Xmx60G -cp "C:\work\weka-3.7.jar;C:\Users\Oracle\wekafiles\packages\AnDE\AnDE.jar" weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier \
  -t train_2.arff -T train_1.arff \
  -classifications "weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV -distribution -p 1 -file predictions_final_multi.csv -suppress" \
  -threshold-file umbral_multi.csv \
  -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Discretize -F -B 10 -M -1.0 -R first-last" \
  -W weka.classifiers.bayes.AveragedNDependenceEstimators.A1DE -- -F 1 -M 1.0 -S
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Weka exception: No value given for -S option.
```

Which is weird, since this was not a problem with the GUI. In the GUI, the Information box says that `-S` it's just a flag ("Subsumption Resolution can be achieved by using -S option"), so it shouldn't expect any number at all, which is consistent with what I got using the Explorer.

So then, what's the deal with the `-S` option when using the command line? Looking at the error text given by weka, I found this:

```
Options specific to classifier weka.classifiers.bayes.AveragedNDependenceEstimators.A1DE:

-D
        Output debugging information

-F <int>
        Impose a frequency limit for superParents        (default is 1)
-M <double>
        Specify a weight to use with m-estimate (default is 1)

-S <int>
        Specify a critical value for specialization-generalilzation SR (default is 100)

-W
        Specify if to use weighted AODE
```

So it seems that this class works in two different ways, depending on which method I use (GUI vs. Command Line).

The solution I found, at least for the meantime, was to write `-S 100` on my script. Is this really the same as just putting `-S` in the GUI?

Thanks in advance.
JM

Answer (score 1):

I've had a play with this Classifier, and can confirm that what you are experiencing on your end is consistent with what I have here.  From the GUI, the -S Option (subsumption Resolution) requires no parameters while the Command Prompt does (specialization-generalization SR).

They don't sound like the same parameter, so you may need to raise this issue with the developer of the third party package if you would like to know more information on these parameters.  You can find this information from the Tools -> Package Manager -> AnDE, which will point you to the contacts for the library.